# Is there a build-in function in R to check whether the variable type is preserved?

Tags: r

Assume you have an input `a` which goes into an existing function `fun`. I am looking for a function `preserved(a, fun(a))`, which returns `TRUE`, if the type is unchanged, `FALSE` otherwise.

Example:

```
a <- 1L # [1] 1 - integer
b <- a[FALSE] # integer(0)
c <- a[2] # [1] NA
d <- ncol(a) # NULL
e <- a/0 # [1] Inf
f <- 1 # [1] 1 - numeric
g <- as.factor(a) # [1] 1 Levels: 1
```

Expected output:

```
preserved(a, 2L) = TRUE
preserved(a, b) = FALSE
preserved(a, c) = FALSE
preserved(a, d) = FALSE
preserved(a, e) = FALSE
preserved(a, f) = FALSE
preserved(a, f) = FALSE
preserved(a, g) = FALSE
```

A bad hack (not vectorized) would be

```
preserved <- function(a, b) {
  if (length(b) == length(a)) {
    if (is.na(b) == is.na(a) & 
        class(b) == class(a) &
        is.null(b) == is.null(a) &
        is.nan(b) == is.nan(a) &
        is.factor(b) == is.factor(a)) {
      return(TRUE)
    } else {
      return(FALSE)
    }
  } else {
    return(FALSE)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your function looks like you want more requirements than just `type` being preserved. `a` and `b` are both of class `integer`

Comment: @MikeH. You are rigtht, but in many cases I would not consider an empty integer as integer. Something like a variable defined in C via `int a`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to compare two objects, you probably want to use `all.equal()` or `identical()` rather than trying to generate every possible pairwise combination of classes (since that number could be infinite).

Something close to what you want that might be more useful is applying `makeActiveBinding()` to issue messages (or warnings or errors) if type coercion is attempted:

```
# active binding
preserved <- local( {
    x <- NULL
    function(v) {
        if (!missing(v)) {
            if (class(x) != class(v)) {
                message(sprintf("Object is being coerced from %s to %s", class(x), class(v)))
            }
            x <<- v
        }
        x
    }
})
makeActiveBinding("z", preserved, .GlobalEnv)
z
## NULL
z <- 2
## Object is being coerced from NULL to numeric
z <- "hello"
## Object is being coerced from numeric to character
z <- factor("a", levels = c("a", "b", "c"))
## Object is being coerced from character to factor
z
## [1] a
## Levels: a b c
```

Comment: But then you still have values `integer`, `NA` and `ìnteger(0)`. Furthermore, it won't distinguish between `1.345` and `1.345/0` as they are both `numeric`.

Comment: Sure. As Mike H. noted above, you're asking for comparisons of multiple features of objects (`mode()` but also `length()`). There's no built-in function to do that so you'll have to decide exactly what your rules are then write the appropriate function. Perhaps update your question to specify what else you want to be non-comparable aside from class or mode. Note too that `NA` is classed in R (see `NA_real_`, `NA_character_`, etc.).

Comment: Ok, I think you made me aware that this is a problem of my code and not of R ;-) I have to go through my code again with the new knowledge and decide afterwards, how to proceed - but thanks again: I was not aware of that option.